# How to call this "`ng-bind-html`" inside "`title`" tag?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use "`ng-bind-html`" directive inside "`title`" tag to render currency value with currency symbol but the expression is not evaluating.

This is how I am tring:

```
$scope.salary= 10000;
$scope.currencySymbol = '&#8364;';//€
<div title="{{ng-bind-html= 'salary |currency:(currencySymbol+' '): 0'}}"> //This is not working
<span ng-bind-html="salary |currency:(currencySymbol+' '): 0"> </span> //working fine and renders €10000
```

Its working fine when I display inside `<span>` tag but I want to display the same formatted value in `<title>` tag as well.

So wondering how to call this "`ng-bind-html`" inside "`title`" tag to display the same output as it is in `<span>` tag?

Comment: bind-html is used to bind the value of the element, not attribute. Use a function or variable for the title attribute, function most likely better

Comment: @Huangism I tried using a function nd called $sce,trustashtml function but not getting the desired output.

Comment: Make sure the string in the attribute does NOT have html code in it

Answer (score 3):

[`ng-bind-html` is a directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml). Curly braces are for expressions. A directive will not be processed from within an expression.

Rewrite your expression as follows:

```
<div title="{{ salary | currency:currencySymbol: 0}}"></div>
```

and replace your `currencySymbol` value with the desired string for the currency prefix. `$scope.currencySymbol = "€ ";`

[Here is a working plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/gku6wi2zDTg8fG7F?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1)

[Additional documentation on the currency filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency)

[Related documentation on expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

If you are truly fixated on processing your currency symbol dynamically and treating it as html, you will need to write a custom currency filter which accepts an sceHtmlString. Javascript strings support unicode, so your provided use-case does not appear to require this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this you can add title to div. But it will not be visible as title is not a text field.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div ng-bind-html="myText"></div>
 <span>Currency Example:</span>
      <div> {{ salary | currency:currencySymbol: 0}} </div>
       <div title=" {{ salary | currency:currencySymbol: 0}}"> nodata</div>
     <span>Currency Example ng-bindhtml</span>
     <span ng-bind-html="myText"></span>
     <p ng-bind-html="myText"></p>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.myText = "My name is: <h1>  111 John Doe</h1>";
     $scope.salary = 10000;
   $scope.salaryhtml = "<p> €10000 </p>";
  $scope.currencySymbol = "€";
  $scope.myText ="  <h1>$ 1000 </h1>";
});
</script>



</body>
</html>
```